# MySQL fast retrieve last record in each group

Tags: mysql, sql, database, logging, query-optimization

I have a table with logs of devices' GPS data `logs(id - PK AI, device_id - FK, lat - DECIMAL, long - DECIMAL, time - DATETIME)`. Id is a primary key and there's an `index on (id, device_id)` and I want to get the latest records for each device.

My current query is:

```
SELECT * FROM devices
WHERE devices.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM devices GROUP BY device_id
)
```

On a table with 1.5 million records and 5 unique devices the query takes 8 seconds. Is it possible to optimize it? The devices are sending data every second and I'm expecting to have 2000 devices total.

It's too slow even with 5 devices.

Another query I have is selecting the route of a device in a time period. That also takes 10 seconds for a period of a day.

Is MySQL the right choice for the task? Should I choose another database? Is there a way to make the queries faster?

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2de1aa/1/0)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Edited with a fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2de1aa/1/0

Comment: You need to add `INDEX(device_id, id)`.  Meanwhile, `INDEX(id, device_id)` is probably useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try each of these two queries. Usually at least one will work well for me with "max row" queries lines yours.

Query 1:

```
SELECT
d.*
FROM devices d
LEFT OUTER JOIN devices larger_d
ON larger_d.device_id = d.device_id
AND larger_d.id > d.id
WHERE larger_d.device_id IS NULL
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
d.*
FROM devices d
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
MAX(id) AS id,
device_id
FROM devices d
GROUP BY device_id
) largest_d
ON largest_d.device_id = d.device_id
AND largest_d.id = d.id
```

In both cases, you will need an index on `(device_id,id)` before you run these queries.

In response to your comments on other peoples' answers, the `(id,device_id`) index is not equivalent to this one we are suggesting. You do not need to remove it, however it will slow down inserts (just like all indexes do). However, for this query it is not useful, and so you can probably remove it if you don't have a specific reason to keep it.

Comment: The first one is timing out but the second one - WOW - Query took 0.0080 seconds!

Comment: Can you explain how the second query is working that fast?

Comment: On a precise technical level? No, I just have used it for years because it is the recommended way to do queries such as yours:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html Mostly, it is fast because it is not slow. Using an `OR` is usually slow, which is what your `IN` statement is doing in your query. So even though our subqueries are basically the same, the fact that mine uses a `JOIN` vs yours uses `IN` is the difference. My best explanation is that the optimizer is simply designed to work best with JOINs, so my query 2 works best.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following.  First, rewrite the code as:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM devices d
WHERE d.id = (SELECT MAX(d2.id) FROM devices d2 WHERE d2.device_id = d.device_id);
```

But first create an index on `devices(device_id, id)`.

EDIT:

I wonder if some outer optimization would help, such as using `datetime`:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM devices d
WHERE d.datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND
      d.id = (SELECT MAX(d2.id)
              FROM devices d2
              WHERE d2.device_id = d.device_id AND
                    d2.datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
             );
```

For this, yo would also want an index on `devices(datetime, device_id)`.

Comment: Results in timeout. Query takes too long

Comment: Should I create the index on (device_id, id) and drop the one on (id, device_id)?

Comment: With the index on (device_id, id) the query timeouts again.

Comment: @lam3r4370 . . . Can you tell from the `explain` if the index is working?

Comment: It was using the FK index on device_id. I changed it to use the index on (device_id, id) but it's still timing out

Comment: The optimization is an interesting idea, I'll probably use it later when there's more data in the table but I think that I want to see all devices and some of the devices may not have sent data in the last hour.

@Willem's second query is working like a charm!